# Changing an element's value in a non-certain-sized multidimensional array using user-specified input in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I've been building a storage system (like a file system) on my website using PHP.

Users are allowed to rename the items which are stored using an associative multidimensional array:

```
array(2) {
  ["folder1"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["file1"]=>
    string(4) "15kb"
    ["file2"]=>
    string(4) "1kb"
  }
  ["folder2"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["file3"]=>
    string(4) "77kb"
    ["file4"]=>
    string(6) "96kb"
    ["folder3"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["file5"]=>
      string(4) "77kb"
      ["file6"]=>
      string(6) "123kb"
    }
  }
}
```

When a user renames an item, a path will be sent from client-side:

```
$filetree = '["folder1"=>["file1"=>"15kb","file2"=>"69kb"],"folder2"=>["file3"=>"77kb","file4"=>"6969kb","folder3"=>["file5"=>"77kb","file6"=>"6969kb"]]]';
$userinputpath = "folder2/folder3";
$userinputpath = explode("/",$userinput);
$targetoldname = "file6";
$targetnewname = "filex";
foreach($userinputpath as $dirname)
    {
        if(array_key_exists($dirname,$filetree))
        {
            $filetree = $filetree[$dirname];
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Failed";
            exit();
        }
    }
if(array_key_exists($targetoldname ,$filetree))
{
    $filetree[$targetnewname] = $filetree[$targetoldname];
    unset($filetree[$targetoldname]);
}
```

But then, I need to save the new array into a file by encoding it into JSON. However, the original file tree is lost already, and I cannot figure out a way to get the version of the whole file tree with the renamed item.

Is there any way to rename the item without reassigns and foreach, or any way that can get the item renamed with the whole file tree is still there? Note that the user's input may vary every time, so I cannot simply `$filetree[$userinputpath[0]][$userinputpath[1]]`as there might be more directories or fewer.

Thank you for reading this time consuming paragraph :) Any suggestion will be apprciated.

Comment: If there are anything unclear, please notify me, I can do additional explanations if needed, thx :)

Comment: May more than 1 folders have "same file name" like folder3 & folder2 both have a file named file7 while folder3 is a child of folder2? I try to understand that you have a tree or dag structure according to the graph theory.

Comment: @Ersin Yes, it’s legit. Thx for asking me to clarify it :)

Comment: Basically, I want a function that can change the value(or key) of any element in any multidimensional array (note that the array can have 1 dimension only).

Answer (score 0):

Your nested folder/files structure is a [Directed acyclic graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) (DAG) structure. {NOTE: "Tree" word in your question is inapprppriate since tree is a term in graph theory which is different than a DAG. In a tree, each node has exactly 1 parent. In a DAG however, a node may have more than 1 parents.}

Also your DAG is always full dynamic without any possible static simplification since your users are allowed to rename the items. They can even rename "folder1" to "folder_QWERTY".

Also a fact that you always at least have 1 -even dummy- root. Even if folder1 name may be edited, then your dummy root is let's say C: folder of the computer/server. (the level that users are unable to edit the name)

**your question 1**

> But then, I need to save the new array into a file by encoding it into JSON. However, the original file tree is lost already, and I cannot figure out a way to get the version of the whole file tree with the renamed item.

You may utilize [time(): int](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) . of the transactions to make your DAG versions traceable in a database. Each file and each folder is a node (element of nodes) and also there is a history table.

Please observe in the tables below that:

at time of 1647258813, your DAG updated (dag_history table). You know that root cause was "node9 update". If you need to trace what was the previous state of "node9"; then you may explore that its name has been changed from "nodes" table.

If you insert/update/delete any node from nodes, if you also insert the json_history row(s) accordingly; then you'll never loose your traceability.

Since name of a file/folder is updateable by the user, you shouldn't use them as primary keys. Each node must have a unique id given by you.

```
nodes
-----
_id     _name        _children   _parents        _time        node_rev
node_1  ... ...
node_3  ... ...
node9   file_1       null        {node1,node3}   1647253000   0
node9   file_QWERTY  null        {node1,node3}   1647258813   1


dag_history
-------
_time           _json   _action  _json_rev   node
1647258702      {...}   insert      0        null
1647258813      {...}   update      1        node9
```

**your question 2**

> I want a function that can change the value(or key) of any element in any multidimensional array

As you already mentioned in your question, this is only possible by loops (walking through the multi dimensional dynamic array.)

Simplest DAG algorithm that suits for your case is [Breadth-first_search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)  (bfs) or Depth-first_search (dfs) algorithm. Of course you may create a custom algorithm which suits your needs better by the help of bfs/dfs.

bfs and dfs common point is each node is visited once but only once.

bfs visits the DAG layer by layer. (1st: the root, 2nd: children of root, 3rd: children of children of root, etc.)

dfs visits the DAG with deepest_child approach. (1st: the root, 2nd: leftmost child of the root, 3rd: leftmost child of the child of the root , etc.)

```
**bfs** pseudocode:

Visit each node once but only once layer by layer      

Input: A graph G and a starting vertex root of G

G may be represented with an adjacency list like:

G = [
    'folder1' => [ 'folder2', 'file1', 'folder3', ... ] ,
    'folder2' => [ 'file2', 'file1' ] ,
    'folder3' => [ 'file4', 'file5' ] ,
    ...
]

Output: Manipulate while visiting current node or child/children nodes.

In your case, if you want to change the name from file3 to X_File for example; 
then you'll do this at row 7 below and will just return (not to continue to walk 
through).

 1  procedure BFS(G, root) is
 2      let Q be a queue
 3      label root as explored
 4      Q.enqueue(root)
 5      while Q is not empty do
 6          v := Q.dequeue()
 7          if v is the goal then
 8              return v
 9          for all edges from v to w in G.adjacentEdges(v) do
10              if w is not labeled as explored then
11                  label w as explored
12                  Q.enqueue(w)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I’ve learnt a lot more knowledge about graph theory through your answer! However, I have some questions after reading your ans as shown below: in terms of computer science / data structures, I think my file tree is actually a *tree*. Also, I think each node only has one direct parent, as the same file names in different directories are considered as different files. I am currently still a student, if there are anything not correct, please correct me :)

Comment: I am currently trying out the algorithms you have mentioned, thx for suggesting them!

Comment: for trees, you can just visit each node (you don't need bfs/dfs) since you have no possibility to visit a node more than once because each node has a unique and only one parent. glad to help you since I needed these algorithms that i coded for my job related personal app. I'm an engineer however not a software one. our cases are similar.